# How to load pdf files in nextjs using webpack file-loader (404 Error)

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, next.js13, file-loader

In my nextjs app, I want to add a button which user clicks on it and a pdf file downloads. I added the pdf file to `public/documents/` and imported it and added it to `link href`. But after clicking it, it shows a 404 page even the generated file is exist and i can watch it on Chrome inspect > sources (in _next). I am using webpack file-loader.

Next config:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  output: "standalone",
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|gif|mp4|pdf)$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

My page code:

```js
import LeaderInstructions from "@documents/leaders-instructions.pdf";

...
//other codes
...

<a
      href={LeaderInstructions}
      target="_blank"
>
```

Anyone knows what should I do?

Comment: File-loader, Url-loader and Raw-loader were replaced by the assets modules in webpack 5.  You should create a new rule using asset/source for the pdf or just switch the loader to asset for the existing rule.  https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Vayne Valerius. I updated to webpack 5 method and works now! Config code:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  output: "standalone",
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(pdf)$/,
      type: "asset/resource",
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing the PDF directly, you can try referencing it using its relative path from the public directory.

```
<a
  href="/documents/leaders-instructions.pdf"
  target="_blank"
>
  Download Leader Instructions PDF
</a>
```

If you want to keep using the imported PDF, you can try something like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const router = useRouter();

const downloadPDF = () => {
  router.push('/documents/leaders-instructions.pdf');
}

<button onClick={downloadPDF}>Download PDF</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions. Does your app have permission to access the file? Also, check your filename for spaces at the end. You may need to use trim to remove extraneous characters.

Comment: File permissions are ok. I checked the chrome inspect element -> source section which contains all files of website and i saw that the PDF file is created. I right clicked it and selected Open in new tab. the file opened in a new tab with correct name, but again it shows 404 error. I guess it's a nextjs error. Not webpack. because webpack file loader, loaded the file correctly, but nextjs doesnt show the file

Comment: Of course, there may be a problem with the webpack. Because the size of the file I see in the tools is 0kb